# 'bash: cleos: command not found' in Docker's WAX Dev image (Windows 10)?

Tags: cleos, docker, bash

I run Docker setup (Windows PowerShell, Admin rights):

```
docker run -it --name waxdev -v c:\wax:/wax waxteam/dev bash
docker run -it --name waxcdt -v c:\wax:/wax waxteam/cdt bash
```

then try to use `cleos` in the command line, but get the message:

```
bash: cleos: command not found
```

How could I fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Same problem :( Is there any solution ?

Comment: @sefa, no, actually. Just started to use Web IDE: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-web-ide

Comment: go to your own directory and try again. it is working with alias now.

Comment: @sefa this doesn't fix the problem in a proper way, issues arise in calling a deprecated version of `cleos`, in compilation, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I've found some workaround to fix the problem:

```
root@a65bebbdd88c:/# find / -type f -name cleos
/tmp/leap/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/DEB/wax-leap-3.2.0wax01-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/base/usr/local/share/bash-completion/completions/cleos
/tmp/leap/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/DEB/wax-leap-3.2.0wax01-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/base/usr/local/bin/cleos
/tmp/leap/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/TGZ/wax-leap-3.2.0wax01-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/usr/local/share/bash-completion/completions/cleos
/tmp/leap/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/TGZ/wax-leap-3.2.0wax01-ubuntu18.04-x86_64/usr/local/bin/cleos
/tmp/leap/build/bin/cleos
/tmp/leap/build/programs/cleos/bash-completion/completions/cleos
/tmp/leap/build/programs/cleos/cleos
/tmp/leap/libraries/cli11/bash-completion/completions/cleos
root@a65bebbdd88c:/# alias cleos=/tmp/leap/build/bin/cleos
root@a65bebbdd88c:/# cleos
ERROR: RequiredError: A subcommand is required
Command Line Interface to EOSIO Client
Usage: /tmp/leap/build/bin/cleos [OPTIONS] SUBCOMMAND

Options:
  -h,--help              Print this help message and exit
...
```

The same should be done for `nodeos` and `keosd` too.

It is still an enigma for me why this does not work from the case (aka Docker's image)?

**UPDATE:**

WAX Docker images have been outdated months ago.

It seems the most workable environment to develop WAX, RNG Oracle and AtomicAssets smart contracts can be currently installed from [here](https://github.com/AntelopeIO/DUNE).